# Cannot view splash-screen in Intel XDK (cordova app)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, splash-screen, intel-xdk

Using Intel XDK, I am developing a mobile app. I included the cordova splash-screen plugin and generated the splash-screen images using Intel XDK's "Launch Icons and Splash Screens" feature. Then I tried to test the splash-screen using the Simulate tab of Intel XDK, but the splash-screen is not showing.

Is it possible to view the splash-screen in Intel XDK? If not, how can I view it on my Android smartphone?

Comment: I have no idea on intel XDK. Using cordova you can show hide splash screens.